Coding a custom boss in Minecraft
I am trying to make a custom boss in Minecraft but the command won't work. I need help.
summon evoker ~ ~ ~ {
    CustomName: '[
        {
            "text": "The True Sorcerer",
            "color": "gray",
            "bold": true
        }
    ]',
    CustomNameVisible: 1b,
    Health: 250,
    FallFlying: 1b,
    Glowing: 1b,
    OnGround: 1b,
    PersistenceRequired: 1b,
    active_effects: [
        {
            id: resistance,
            duration: 99999,
            amplifier: 2,
            show_particles: 0b
        }
    ],
    PatrolLeader: 1b,
    HandItems: [
        {
            id: stick,
            count: 1
        }
    ],
    HandDropChances: [0f],
    ArmorItems: [
        {
            id: netherite_boots,
            count: 1
        },
        {
            id: netherite_leggings,
            count: 1
        },
        {
            id: iron_chestplate,
            components: {
                custom_name: '[
                    "",
                    {
                        "text": "∋",
                        "italic": false,
                        "color": "white"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "V",
                        "italic": false
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "ex",
                        "italic": false,
                        "color": "gray"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": " Wi",
                        "italic": false,
                        "color": "red"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "ng",
                        "italic": false,
                        "color": "gray"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "s",
                        "italic": false
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "∈",
                        "italic": false,
                        "color": "white"
                    }
                ]',
                lore: ['
                    [
                        "",
                        {
                            "text": "Small vex wings,",
                            "italic": false
                        }
                    ]',
                    '[
                        "",
                        {
                            "text": "not big enough for you to fly",
                            "italic": false
                        }
                    ]',
                    '[
                        "",
                        {
                            "text": "but big enough to give you a large jump increase.",
                            "italic": false
                        }
                    ]'
                ],
                enchantments: {
                    levels: {
                        mending: 1,
                        projectile_protection: 4,
                        protection: 2,
                        thorns: 3,
                        unbreaking: 3
                    }
                },
                damage: 0,
                repair_cost: 10,
                custom_data = {
                    vexwing: 1b
                },
                count: 1
            },
            {
                id: netherite_helmet,
                count: 1
            }
        ],
        ArmorDropChances: [
            0f,
            0f,
            1f,
            0f
        ],
        attributes: [
            {
                id: attack_speed,
                base: 2f
            },
            {
                id: follow_range,
                base: 32f
            },
            {
                id: entity_interaction_range,
                base: 4f
            },
            {
                id: "generic.max_health",
                base: 250f
            }
        ]
    }


Could you explain what’s going wrong? Welcome to Arqade!

You’re missing a closing brace } at the very end. But I assume that that’s just a copy-paste error.
